# How to join the two tables with the same primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to join the two tables with the same primary key?

Table1:

```
Item_ID   Name   Date
I1        ABC    21-03-2018
I2        EFG    21-04-2018
I3        XYZ    21-05-2018
I4        LKJ    21-06-2018
```

Table2:

```
Item_ID   Cost   
I1        21    
I1        54
I1        27
I1        32
I2        65 
I2        75 
I3        45  
I3        46
I4        34
I4        74
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: By definition, a PK is unique because it identifies, without doubt or duplicates, a record. So [Table2].[Item_ID] is a FK

Comment: I've rolled back your edit; text is much preferable to an image.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
ON A.Item_Id = B.Item_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp):

```
SELECT name, date, cost from Table1, Table2 INNER JOIN table2 AS two ON two.item_id=item_id
```

Next time, please make a search on google. There are many easy examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query.

You can Join the tables through "INNER JOIN" .
t1 & t2 is alias for Tables. So you can read the same column name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 
 ON t1.Item_ID=t2.Item_ID
```